# HighCharts - modify format of spiderweb graph

Tags: jquery, graph, highcharts

I am currently working on a spiderweb graph with three series displayed on the screen.  The values range from 0-4.

The fiddle below is an example of the data I am using.  The actual graph is just the demo graph from the website

http://jsfiddle.net/yjm5D/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Allocated Budget',
        data: [4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        name: 'Actual Spending',
        data: [4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
        name: 'Actual Spending',
        data: [4, 2, 0, 1, 4, 0],
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]
```

The problem I have is that the zero values go to the centre of the graph.  This is rather ugly.  What I need to do is move those values slightly out from the centre point to create more of a shape in the middle.

To do this I did the following:

- Modified the dataset and made all values + 1 before entering them into the graph so the actual range becomes from 1-5 instead of 0-4
- Modified the tooltip to show the data value in the series - 1 (to show values as 0 - 4)
- I am attempting to also modify the dataLabels (the one on the axis) to show the correct value

I would like to know if there is a better method to resolve this problem as I am not satisfied with what I currently have.

Comment: So you need to have interval on yAxis, which will be more smooth ? or something different. If yes please attach mockup how it should look like.

Comment: @SebastianBochan The graph shouldn't show the 0 values at 0.  The whole graph should be shifted from 0-4 to 1-5 but actually show the user values from 0-4

Comment: You can use label formatter and modify content of labels. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter